# Open '*-flat.vmdk' file to restore data

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

vmWare Worstation 10 suddenly crashed.

After trying to reboot the virtual machine next error was shown: 
"*NOT REACHED: d:/build/ob/bora-2844087/bora/lib/disklib/sparseChecker.c:1308*".

After some tests, I have converted '*.vmdk' file to '*-flat.vmdk' with "*Starwind V2V converter*".

Then, making use of "*WinImage*", I have opened the 'flat' file , but this app crashes I try to get the files from "*..\Users\user\path*", then app crashes.

- **Is there any way to open the VMs to get the file save inside them**?

I can create another VM, but at least, I need to restore the data saved in the wrong VM.

KR!

Answer (score 0):

Have you try repair `VMDK` disk first?

```
vmware-vdiskmanager.exe -R <your-disk.vmdk>
```

...and if you already have '-flat.vmdk' image of your disk, you can mount this raw image using free app [OSFMount](http://www.osforensics.com/tools/mount-disk-images.html), but you must first change extension of `.vmdk` file to `.raw` or `.dd` to OSFMount working properly.

Comment: - vmware-vdiskmanager.exe does nothing.
- OSFMount works, VM is mounted but I can't access to 'users data', they are all corrupted. So, I think it is all done :(

Comment: on mounted image, you can try `chkdsk` or `TestDisk`/`PhotoRec`

Comment: Nothing works! Finally, I lose my files and need to install a new VM. I do not know why the first one crashes, I hope there will not happen again.